# Time to live support for hazelcast ISet and IList

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hazelcast `IMap` supports time to live for map entries.
`IMap` has the method for this [like](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#put(K,%20V,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

My question is, does Hazelcast `ISet` and `IList` support time to live for entries?

I can not find in documents [ISet](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ISet.html) and [IList](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IList.html)

Mathod should like `set.add(object, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't support this for ISet and IList.

What you can consider though is implementing Set or List functionality on top of **IMap**, e.g:

- to implement a Set features you can simply put your values as keys of IMap with some pre-defined constant value, like a standard Java HashSet is doing with HashMap
- to have a List features you can use Hazelcast **IAtomicLong** to generate indexes and **IMap** to store values under the generated keys, but still it won't be as performant as **IList** and may have limitations

If you go that way you can use **IMap** API with **time-to-live** argument to ensure that your values expire over the time.